# Compiler error when not including the parameter types from another constructor

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I'm using C# under VS2012 v.11.0.61030.00 Update 4. I have a class with two constructors: one for normal use, and one that injects a dependency for the purposes of unit testing.

```
using ServiceLayer;

namespace PresentationLayer
{
    public class Orchestrator
    {
        private NumberService svc;

        public Orchestrator(int i)
        {
            svc = new NumberService(i);
        }

        public Orchestrator(NumberService providedService)
        {
            svc = providedService;
        }

        public int Get()
        {
            return svc.GetInt();
        }
    }
}
```

The "NumberService" is in a second project:

```
namespace ServiceLayer
{
    public class NumberService
    {
        private int x;

        public NumberService(int i)
        {
            x = i;
        }

        public int GetInt()
        {
            return x;
        }
    }
}
```

The PresentationLayer project is in turn referenced by the app (in this case, a console app):

```
using System;
using PresentationLayer;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Orchestrator o = new Orchestrator(8);
            Console.WriteLine(o.Get());
        }
    }
}
```

The line `Orchestrator o = new Orchestrator(8);` throws a compiler error as follows:

`The type 'ServiceLayer.NumberService' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ServiceLayer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.`

This appears to be because VS cannot differentiate between the two constructors without knowing what a NumberService is. However, if I change the number of parameters...

```
public Orchestrator(int i, bool b)
{
    svc = new NumberService(i);
}
```

and

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Orchestrator o = new Orchestrator(8, true);
    Console.WriteLine(o.Get());
}
```

Suddenly it's quite happy to compile. I feel that one of these two behaviors is in error: either it's okay not to know what a given class is, or it's not. Does anyone have a better explanation or fix for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's okay not to understand a particular class when you know that its use is in a member that's definitely not applicable for the call you're making, because you're specifying two arguments and the member only takes one parameter.

It's *not* okay to not know whether the call is even valid, because you don't know (for example) whether there's an implicit conversion from `int` to `NumberService`. In this particular case this couldn't change overload resolution (I *think*...) but in other cases it might. Imagine if your `int` parameter was actually `object`, for example...

Personally I would be very wary of using a class where some of its public API depends on types in an assembly you don't have a reference to. You're operating somewhat in the dark. I suggest you just add an appropriate reference, or make the constructor internal to remove it from the public API. There's no point in having a public API that you don't *actually* want other code to be able to understand. If this is just for the sake of unit testing, then make the constructor `internal` and use `InternalsVisibleTo` to expose it (and other internal members) to your unit test assembly.

Comment: The main problem with that suggestion is that we don't want the app layer to be "aware" of the service layer so that it could be unplugged and replaced without touching the presentation code. We worked around the problem by changing the unit testable constructor's parameter to an object and casting it to the service class. We also discussed moving the NumberService to a different project that could be included in both, but as the "real" implementation of this problem is an interface, it could cause some circular dependencies.

Comment: @Martin: In that case I suggest you don't make that constructor public - make it internal, and use InternalsVisibleTo to expose it to the unit test code. Basically decide whether you want other code to see it or not - they shouldn't be able to see it if they're not able to understand it.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like exactly what I needed! We agreed that we will use an interface contract pattern in the future, but it's not worth the time to refit the existing solution at this point.

Answer (score 0):

This is an educated guess - I haven't checked the language spec to confirm this - but I would imagine that the compiler chooses overloads based on a number of criteria. If there are 20 overloads of a given method, it's far more efficient to ignore the overloads with a different number of arguments to the call you're making, because these are *obviously* not the one being called.

However, once you're narrowed down to the list of overloads with the same number of arguments as are being passed, it's more complex: there may be implicit conversions from what's being passed to one of the overload types, for example, that make resolution unclear. Without the compiler knowing all of the types of the available arguments, it can't make that decision reliably and so fails.

Adding the extra argument means that it never needs to look at the overload using the `NumberService`, and so the compiler doesn't need the assembly reference to resolve the overload.

Answer (score 0):

You can eliminate the error by making dependency-injection enabled constructor overload `internal` thus eliminating the need for the compiler to know if `int` can be casted to `numberService`

Comment: This is the best solution for my situation, combined with Jon Skeet's suggestion of InternalsVisibleTo exposing the required constructor to the unit testing project.

Comment: @Martin , yeah, this is the way to go.